# scala sortWith not work

Tags: java, scala, sorting, arraylist

I need to make sort of java ArrayList on scala

It is sorting methos of the class, files - field of the. To use ArrayList i'v imported java.util.ArrayList and  scala.collection.JavaConversions._

```
other imports ...
import java.io.File
import java.util.ArrayList
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

class SortReplays(val files:ArrayList[File]) {  
def sort(kindOfSort:String) = {
    kindOfSort match {
      case "name" => files.sortWith(compareFileNames);
      case "length" => files.sortWith(compareGameLength);
      case "date" => files.sortWith(compareGameDates);
    }
  }
```

this is one of comparators, it is also the method of SortReplays

```
def compareGameLength(file1:File, file2:File) = {
    val length1:Long = ReplayViewerController.getGameLength(file1)
    val length2:Long = ReplayViewerController.getGameLength(file2)
    length1 < length2
  }
```

This what I do in java

```
Service.out("scala sorting by length");
      long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
      ArrayList<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(files));
      SortReplays sort = new SortReplays(fileList);
      sort.sort("length");
      Service.out("scala sort by length, time spend: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t1));
      try {
        controller.refreshLengths(fileList.toArray(new File[0]));
        controller.refreshReplays(fileList.toArray(new File[0]));
      } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
      }
```

I have expected that files will be sorted - but it doesn't happens, time spends, but list no change at all. 
Also I have done the same in java

```
public void sortLengths(ArrayList<File> files) {
    Collections.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {

      @Override
      public int compare(File arg0, File arg1) {
        long l1;
        long l2;
        try {
          l1 = getGameLength(arg0);
          l2 = getGameLength(arg1);
          if(l1 < l2)
            return -1;
          else if(l1 == l2)
            return 0;
          else
            return 1;
        } catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
          return 0;
        }
      }

    });
  }
```

And it works as expected

Comment: The `sortWith` method doesn't sort inplace, it return a sorted sequence without modify the raw data.

Comment: There is a serious misunderstanding of how the collection API works, on immutability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the calls of `files.sortWith` in `SortReplays.sort` return a `Seq`, but do not modify the `files` list.

To fix the issue, you need to:

First, return a Java `List` from `def sort`. Can be solved by adding an implicit converter:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
```

...

```
private implicit def toJavaList[T](seq: Seq[T]): util.List[T] = {
  new util.ArrayList(seq.asJavaCollection)
}

def sort(kindOfSort: String): util.List[File] = {
  kindOfSort match {
    case "name" => files.sortWith(compareFileNames);
    case "length" => files.sortWith(compareGameLength);
    case "date" => files.sortWith(compareGameDates);
  }
}
```

BTW, it's a good practice in Scala to specify an explicit return type for public functions (`: util.List[File]` in this case).

`ArrayList` declarations should also be changed into `List`, to respect the *program-to-interface* principle.

Second, in your Java-side code, some changes are necessary:

```
SortReplays sort = new SortReplays(Arrays.asList(files));
List<File> fileList = sort.sort("length");
Service.out("scala sort by length, time spend: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t1));
try {
  controller.refreshLengths(fileList.toArray(new File[0]));
  controller.refreshReplays(fileList.toArray(new File[0]));
} catch (Exception e1) {
  e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

BTW, avoid catching `Exception`, this is ugly.